# How to reference a touch using Hash Code?

Tags: hash, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I am making a 2d physics platform game. I am controlling the main character using left,right and jump buttons. I am however having trouble handling multiple touches. I have read about the hash code to reference each touch and hence figure out what button or combination of buttons is being pressed. I am not able to find an example implementation of this hash code though.

Can someone point me to an example that shows how to use the hash code? If you have a suggestion on anyother way to implement the controls that will be appreciated too.

Thanks

Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

See answers to this question:

[In cocos2d how do you implement a touch hash code and reference it later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111366/in-cocos2d-how-do-you-implement-a-touch-hash-code-and-reference-it-later)

Comment: I had seen that link. But he never got around to implementing it. I am not able to see an example implementation of the hash code.